# Парсер на beautifulSoap выводит только первый результат и не продолжает итерации

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup

Пишу парсер для сайта анекдотов https://nekdo.ru/. Когда пытаюсь спарсить левый список тем этим же кодом, всё работает. Но когда пытаюсь спарсить чисто для примера тексты с первой страницы, парсер выдает только самый первый текст и не идет дальше, хотя items вроде как имеет нужный формат.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import cards as cards
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import sqlite3
url = 'https://nekdo.ru/'
base_url = 'https://nekdo.ru'

HEADERS = {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

def get_html(url, params=""):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    items = soup.find_all("div", class_="content")
    arr = []
    print(items)

    for item in items:
       arr.append(
            {
                "text": item.find("div", class_="text").get_text()
                #"category": item.find("a").get("title")
            }
        )
    print(arr)

html = get_html(url)
get_content(html.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы вывели количество элементов, то заметили бы что-то идет не так:

```py
print(len(items))
# 1
```

Поэтому, у вас тут идет 1 итерация:

```py
for item in items:
```

И добавляете первый элемент из `"div", class_="content"`:

```py
item.find("div", class_="text").get_text()
```

Т.е. вам нужно сначала `find`, чтобы найти `"div", class_="content"`, а у него вызывать и итерировать по `find_all`, чтобы искать `"div", class_="text"`

Но мне больше нравится использовать css-селекторы, поэтому пример с `select`:

```py
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    arr = []
    for item in soup.select('.content .text'):
        arr.append({
           "text": item.get_text()
        })
    print(len(arr), arr)
```

Результат:

```
30 [{'text': 'Приходит мужик в аптеку и жалуется:- У Вас презервативы бракованные!- А в чем дело?- Да какой не надену, все гнутся!'}, {'text': 'Фантазия человека настолько безгранична, что ее хватило только на четыре пальца из пяти.'}, ...
```

---

ЗЫ.

В питоне есть парсер из коробки - `html.parser`:

```py
BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!
Действительно заработало "Т.е. вам нужно сначала find, чтобы найти "div", class_="content", а у него вызывать и итерировать по find_all, чтобы искать "div", class_="text".
А lxml использую, так как говорят что он быстрее, а по итогу буду парсить очень много пукнктов

Comment: @ДаниилБородин Можно просто сразу найти все `div`ы с классом `class_="text"`, `items = soup.find_all("div", class_="text")` и затем в цикле вытащить из них только текст `"text": item.get_text()`.

Comment: @ДаниилБородин, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)